# How to Improve Table Performance in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I have 2 table having more than 50 column and above  150,000  rows. Both the tables are in the Relationship (Primary Key and Foreign Key).

I want to run query to fetch the records from the both tables, but it takes lot to time to execute.

How I can improve the performance of both the tables?

Please help me out.

Comment: we are going to need more information if you want some help.  Query, DBMS you are working with, etc.

Comment: You could normalize the tables into multiple tables.  Trim off the old rows..  Compact/shrink the database to remove any white space.

Answer (score 2):

You should provide more info and the EXACT SQL , any way here are some basics (assuming SQL is used)

- Make sure you have have an index defined on each table.
- Make sure you return only the required columns
- Make sure the data types are the same on FK/PK (in case your FK is logical)
- Try not to use functions in WHERE - Sometimes you get performance degradation if you do
- Try not to use OR in WHERE - Sometimes you get performance degradation if you do
- Get the execution plan and see if the indexes are used.

Again, more info is needed.

Answer (score 0):

Please provide used query...

Make sure you have have an index defined on each table and they are used immediately after Where clause in your passed query. Please do not use the Select * in your query instead you use only the required columns and subqueries as well. Run your query only for the specific condition in where clause which returns the number of rows less instead all the of the table records. Keep the same data types for your used key columns in both of the tables.

Check the execution plan and see if the indexes are used.